# Climate change hoax

Tags: climate, climate-change, temperature, earth-observation

I see many scientific articles and newspapers out there saying that the climate change is happening.
Yet, there are people who believe climate change is a hoax and a lie. But I haven't seen any 'scientific' articles that support that climate change is a hoax.

What are some reasons that some people believe that climate change is not real?

And is there any scientific articles (backed up by science) that support that climate change issue is not real? (A link to the website would be very helpful)

Thank you

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion

Comment: There's an entire SE dedicated to scientific skepticism (https://skeptics.stackexchange.com). You might be better off checking there.

Comment: Climate change skeptics have historically used the variability of solar output (which cycles every 11 years) as a potential source.  Then they publish some wild numbers in a physicians journal with no real peer review.  There are no real climate scientists that are skeptical about the existence of human causation.  However, there are several scientists that debate the level at which human activity can alter climate.  In general, those tend to be scientists who profess more than they research.

Comment: The main reason why people don't believe in AGW (or at least pretend not to) boils down to the fact that it would either cost them money (e.g. the Koch brothers) or force them to change their lifestyles.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's explicitly seeking anti-science, and this is a scientific site

Comment: I think it is more fair to say that the base cause of global warming is well understood (anthropogenic carbon dioxide makes the world warmer), some ancillary mechanisms affecting warming are not well understood (positive/negative feedbacks due to changes in cloud formation, as an example), and the economic effects of global warming are mostly estimates. There is valid criticism to be made of climate model's assumptions about feedback mechanisms, or papers about potential economic impact. As far as the world getting hotter goes, that part is pretty much settled.

Comment: If you're looking to understand why some people think it's a hoax (and why more people profess to think that), look for a book called Merchants of Doubt.

Comment: I believe there is insufficient evidence for global warming, but, since it's anti-established science, I can't post it here. Feel free to contact me directly (contact info in my profile) for more.

Comment: Debate shows that global warming topic is a wash. Check out all of the GlobalWarming=good cards here: http://debate-central.ncpa.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Warming.pdf

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Old question, but I think it's unfair to say he's asking seeking anti-science.  He's asking for science based contrary arguments.   Now, there may be none, or they might be weak, but the question as it's written asks for scientific evidence.   That part of it is fair.   I'm not proposing reopening cause I think it's too broad and it's sat too long and may be covered elsewhere, but it's very close to a fair question.

Comment: This would be a great question for the Skeptic stack exchange. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @farrenthorpe points out in a comment, the solar cycles are often pointed out as source of climate variability.

The only peer-reviewed paper that I know of is the following:
[Empirical evidence for a celestial origin of the climate oscillations
and its implications](http://www.fel.duke.edu/~scafetta/pdf/scafetta-JSTP2.pdf) by [Nicola Scafetta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicola_Scafetta) in the Journal of Atmospheric and Solar-Terrestrial Physics.

Nicola Scafetta has oten made the point that "at least 60% of the global
warming observed since 1970 has been induced by the combined effect of the above natural climate
oscillations" in the above paper, in several conferences and grey papers. See [this](http://scienceandpublicpolicy.org/images/stories/papers/originals/climate_change_cause.pdf) for example. But, as far as I know, no-one ever succeeded in reproducing its analysis...

Comment: Scafetta is not a climate scientist. He is a physicist, and a pretty poor one at that, if his papers are anything to go by. Highly selective cherry picking of data, ignorance of the wider picture, dubious understanding of statistical significance, and arbitrary curve fitting without any physical basis. His climate argument is debunked in: http://www.skepticalscience.com/scafetta-widget-problems.html . As for "60% of  global warming since 1970..... being caused by natural climate oscillations" - solid gold humbug!

Comment: As I wrote - it's all covered in the above reference.

Comment: that wasn't in your original answer.. but ok

Answer (score 7):

This stack exchange is about Earth ***Science***. The scientific position is unequivocal in verifying the reality of climate change.  One is free to take a contrary skeptical position, but it isn't supported by climate data, ecological data, glaciology, atmospheric and oceanographic science, modelling, theoretical studies, feedback mechanisms, peer review scrutiny, or the basic premise of scientific method. 'Climate-change as a hoax', or 'global conspiracy' has nothing to do with science. It has everything to do with the psychology of denial, and the short-term expediency of vested big-business interests, notably in the oil and coal industries. So the reason you don't find genuine science articles refuting climate-change is that there aren't any such scientifically credible articles. This statement will of course prompt an avalanche of responses claiming that there is valid denialist science, which highlights the main problem of the internet - that most non-scientists cannot differentiate between junk science and real science. Consequently, they cannot differentiate between the media's beat-up 'controversy', and the exceptionally strong and consistent consensus of the scientific community. 
My advice, writing as a climate change Earth-Scientist, is (1) don't take anyone's word unless it is from a professionally peer-reviewed paper, and (2) for starters, go to something like the World-Bank's climate-change knowledge portal, pick some locations at random, and check out the historic and projected temperature data. Both temperature and rainfall projections are given. I suggest that you concentrate on the temperature - the rainfall projections are less reliable.

Short answer - is there a credible anti-climate-change science site - No.

Comment: "isn't supported by climate data, ecological data, glaciology, atmospheric and oceanographic science, modelling, theoretical studies, feedback mechanisms, peer review scrutiny, or the basic premise of scientific method" i think is not true. Read cards from the GlobalWarming=good from this national debate university. They point to Hadley Climate Research Unit in Britain, the NASA Goddard Institute for 
Space Studies in New York, the Christy group at the University
 of Alabama, and Remote Sensing Systems Inc in California.  http://debate-central.ncpa.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Warming.pdf

Comment: Seth's comment is completely, utterly, totally 100% wrong, and I stand by my original comments. Like creationists, flat earthers etc., your comments would take more time to respond to that I am willing to spend, but for those who take the trouble to look - with an unbiased mind - the evidence is certainly there.

Comment: I don't understand how 24 pages of evidence can be 100% wrong. Especially since it quotes legit scientific studies from legit sources as commented above. I agree there is certainly evidence of global warming and negative effects, but there is also evidence global warming is good, and/or irrelevant on large scale as cited in the above link. Guess we'll agree to disagree

Comment: 24 pages of cherry picked data, misrepresented, distorted, and which fails to take account of contrary evidence can very certainly be wrong. Witness, for example the volumes of drivel pored out by creationists, flat earthers, anti-immunization lobby, the tobacco lobby, coal lobby, etc. In the latter case the American coal industry spent $1/4 Bn on anti-science propaganda, which to this day has turned round American sentiments against rational science. It is quality that counts - not quantity.

Comment: I agree it is definitely cherry picked data, possibly misrepresented and possibly distorted since I didn't read the papers the facts came from. But had to be cherry picked because we can't fit the hundreds of pages these summaries came from or read them in an 8 min speech. Misrepresented and distorted because we are forced to play devils advocate. Even still facts do exist in this data which do not support global warming. Just one: "it cooled by about 0.7C
in 2007. This is the fastest temperature change in the instrumental record and it puts us back where we were in 1930"